# Android PagingLibrary network + database

Tags: android, paging, android-architecture-components, android-paging

I'm working on Messaging app and I am implementing database + network to save chat messages from api and show them from database. I'm using `BoundaryCallback` to fetch message when database has no more data. My api works like this:

```
getlist(       @Query("msgid") long msgid,
               @Query("loadolder") boolean olderOrNewer,
               @Query("showcurrentMessage") boolean showcurrentMessage,
               @Query("MsgCountToLoad") int MsgCountToLoad);
```

- `msgid` : last message id of that chat . if db is empty I request
  with the `chat.getlastmessageid` if the db has data but there was no
  more data I will send last message id in db to load more and if first
  time opening chat, the last message id in db was not equal to
  chat.lastmessageid it's mean there is new message to load.
- `loadolder` : this flag false to tell api load new messages from this
  message id I sent to you and on and if flag set to true means load
  older messages from this message id I sent to you
- `showcurrentMessage`: if true it will give me the current message (`msgid`) too
- `MsgCountToLoad` : how many messages to take from api

question is how to handle this stuff in `Pagginglibrary`? How to tell it to load older or newer message which is based on scrolling position. First time to load data is easy, it will returns null object so I will use the chat.lastmessageid next time opening chat where I could check if `chat.lastmessageid` is equal to `db.lastmessageid` and tell it to load more new messages.

Comment: There's a codelab example that might help : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-paging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PagedList.BoundaryCallback` has two separate APIs for prepending and appending.

You should look to implement these methods:

```
onItemAtEndLoaded
onItemAtFrontLoaded
```

Assuming your initial load loads the most recent messages, and scrolling up loads older messages, you can just pass `true` for `loadolder` in `onItemAtFrontLoaded` and `false` in `onItemAtEndLoaded`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working my last project on Messaging app. One the most important and common things that we do in our projects is to load data gradually from the network or the database maybe because there is a huge number of entities that can’t be loaded at once.

If you are not familiar with paging library or live data concepts please take your time to study them first because I’m not going to talk about them here. There are lots of resources you can use to learn them.

My solution consists of two main parts!

1. Observing the database using Paging Library.
2. Observing the RecyclerView to understand when to request the server for data pages.

For demonstration we are going to use an entity class that represents a Person:

```
@Entity(tableName = "persons")
data class Person(
@ColumnInfo(name = "id") @PrimaryKey val id: Long,
@ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String,
@ColumnInfo(name = "update_time") val updateTime: Long

)
```

**1. Observe the database**

Lets start with the first and easier one:
To observe the database we are going to define a method in our dao that returns a DataSource.Factory<Int, Person>

```
@Dao
interface PersonDao {
@Query("SELECT * FROM persons ORDER BY update_time DESC")
fun selectPaged(): DataSource.Factory<Int, Person>
}
```

And now in our ViewModel we are going to build a PagedList from our factory

```
class PersonsViewModel(private val dao: PersonDao) : ViewModel() {
val pagedListLiveData : LiveData<PagedList<Person>> by lazy {
    val dataSourceFactory = personDao.selectPaged()
    val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setPageSize(PAGE_SIZE)
            .build()
    LivePagedListBuilder(dataSourceFactory, config).build()
}
}
```

And from our view we can observe the paged list

```
class PersonsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_persons)

    viewModel.pagedListLiveData.observe(this, Observer{
        pagedListAdapter.submitList(it)
    })
  }
}
```

Alright, now that is basically what we should do for the first part. Please notice that we are using a PagedListAdapter. Also we can do some more customization on our PagedList.Config object but for simplicity we omit it. Again please notice that we didn’t use a BoundaryCallback on our LivePagedListBuilder.

**2. Observe the RecyclerView**

Basically what we should do here is to observe the list, and based on where in the list we are right now, ask the server the provide us with the corresponding page of data. For observing the RecyclerView position we are going to use a simple library called Paginate.

```
class PersonsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Paginate.Callbacks {
private var page = 0
private var isLoading = false
private var hasLoadedAllItems = false
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_persons)

    viewModel.pagedListLiveData.observe(this, Observer{
        pagedListAdapter.submitList(it)
    })
    Paginate.with(recyclerView, this).build()
 }
override fun onLoadMore() {
    // send the request to get corresponding page
 }
override fun isLoading(): Boolean = isLoading
override fun hasLoadedAllItems(): Boolean = hasLoadedAllItems
}
```

As you can see we bound the Paginate with the recycler view and now we have three callbacks. isLoading() should return the state of network. hasLoadedAllItems() shows whether or not we have reached the last page and there is no more data to load from the server. Most of what we do is implementing the last method onLoadMore().

In this stage we should do three things:

1. Based on the recyclerView position, we ask the server to present us with the right data page.
2. Using the fresh data from the server we update the database, resulting in updating the PagedList and showing the fresh data. Don’t forget we are observing the database!
3. If the request fails we show the error.

With these simple steps we solve two problems.
First of all despite the BoundaryCallbak, that doesn’t have a callback to fetch the already fetched data, we are requesting each page on demand so we can notice the updated entities and also update our own local databse.
Second we can easily show the state of the network and also show the possible network failures.
Sounds fine right? Well we haven’t solved one particular problem yet. And that is what if one entity gets deleted from the remote server. How are we going to notice that! Well that is where ordering of data comes in. With a really old trick of sorting the data we can notice the gaps between our persons. For example we can sort our persons based on their update_time now if the returned JSON page from the server looks like this:

```
{
 "persons": [{
 "id": 1,
 "name": "Reza",
 "update_time": 1535533985000
}, {
 "id": 2,
 "name": "Nick",
 "update_time": 1535533985111
}, {
 "id": 3,
 "name": "Bob",
 "update_time": 1535533985222
}, {
 "id": 4,
 "name": "Jafar",
 "update_time": 1535533985333
}, {
 "id": 5,
 "name": "Feryal",
 "update_time": 1535533985444
}],
 "page": 0,
 "limit": 5,
 "hasLoadedAllItems": false
}
```

Now we can be sure that whether if there is a person in our local database that its update_time is between the first and the last person of this list, but it is not among these persons, is in fact deleted from the remote server and thus we should delete it too.
I hope I was too vague but take a look at the code below

```
override fun onLoadMore() {
if (!isLoading) {
    isLoading = true
    viewModel.loadPersons(page++).observe(this, Observer { response ->
        isLoading = false
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            hasLoadedAllItems = response.data.hasLoadedAllItems
        } else {
            showError(response.errorBody())
        }
    })
  }
}
```

But the magic happens in the ViewModel

```
class PersonsViewModel(
    private val dao: PersonDao,
    private val networkHelper: NetworkHelper
 ) : ViewModel() {
 fun loadPersons(page: Int): LiveData<Response<Pagination<Person>>> {
    val response = 
            MutableLiveData<Response<Pagination<Person>>>()
    networkHelper.loadPersons(page) {
        dao.updatePersons(
                it.data.persons,
                page == 0,
                it.hasLoadedAllItems)
        response.postValue(it)
    }
    return response
   }
 }
```

As you can see we emit the network result and also update our database

```
@Dao
interface PersonDao {
@Transaction
fun updatePersons(
        persons: List<Person>,
        isFirstPage: Boolean,
        hasLoadedAllItems: Boolean) {
    val minUpdateTime = if (hasLoadedAllItems) {
        0
    } else {
        persons.last().updateTime
    }

    val maxUpdateTime = if (isFirstPage) {
        Long.MAX_VALUE
    } else {
        persons.first().updateTime
    }

    deleteRange(minUpdateTime, maxUpdateTime)
    insert(persons)
   }

   @Query("DELETE FROM persons WHERE
        update_time BETWEEN
        :minUpdateTime AND :maxUpdateTime")
   fun deleteRange(minUpdateTime: Long, maxUpdateTime: Long)
   @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
   fun insert(persons: List<Person>)
  }
```

Here in our dao first we delete all the persons that their updateTime is between the first and last person in the list returned from the server and then insert the list into the database. With that we made sure any person that is deleted on the server is also deleted in our local database as well. Also notice that we are rapping these two method calls inside a database @Transaction for better optimization. The changes of the database will be emitted through our PagedList thus updating the ui and with that we are done.

Comment: thank you for your detailed explanation i designed based on ` BoundaryCallback ` but i'm pretty sure your way of doing will work great. this will help someone

Comment: imagine adding an update time variable to your backend models just to make ui things work on the frontend